# Latex outputs HTML code in Rstudio not a table

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, tidyr, kable

I'm new to using LaTex and compilers in general. I've read a number of threads online but I'm not even sure how compilers work. I've downloaded LaTex for my mac and installed it but have no idea how to use it. When I use test code to generate a table, all I get is HTML code output into my console-- The tutorials I'm following online always generate beautiful tables. What am I doing wrong?

```
Given: 

dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]

kable(dt, "html") %>% #HTML version
  kable_styling()

kable(dt, format = "latex", booktabs = T) #Latex, neither work

Output:

\begin{tabular}{lrrrrrr}
\toprule
  & mpg & cyl & disp & hp & drat & wt\\
\midrule
Mazda RX4 & 21.0 & 6 & 160 & 110 & 3.90 & 2.620\\
Mazda RX4 Wag & 21.0 & 6 & 160 & 110 & 3.90 & 2.875\\
Datsun 710 & 22.8 & 4 & 108 & 93 & 3.85 & 2.320\\
Hornet 4 Drive & 21.4 & 6 & 258 & 110 & 3.08 & 3.215\\
Hornet Sportabout & 18.7 & 8 & 360 & 175 & 3.15 & 3.440\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

The code I've seen on Github always presents it in a beautiful looking table. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latex you are generating will render if you are inserting output like that into a pdf. One way to do that would be to create a .Rmd file and then include a "chunk" to render the table. Here are some more [resources about R Markdown files](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-1.html).

````
---
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{booktabs}
output: pdf_document
---

```{r, results = "asis"}
library("dplyr")
library("knitr")

dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]
kable(dt, format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE) 
```
````

Comment: Is there a way to get it to output the table in my console in RStudio?

Comment: @D500, yes can output table in your console, try only this: `kable(dt)`

Comment: It outputs the code in my console if I call up Kable. That's my question.. I can't get a table to output. It's coded in HTML or Latex with >>%%% and etc.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. You want a formatted table output in your console? If you just want to see those data points, you can just view `dt`. The console itself is not meant to render a latex-style table.